# Can PrincipalContext be used to get Active Directory information if computer is not domained joined

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I am using PrincipalContext.  I am receiving "The LDAP server is unavailable."  "Cannot be reached".  I am developing from a machine that is not joined to the domain I want to query.  Does this matter?  Do I need to pass admin creds to connect to AD, so I can query or search it?

My code resembles this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/usingAccountManagement.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does matter. But you can get your site access by setting an `<identity>` tag in web.config to a user with ldap reading privileges:

```
<system.web>
<identity userName="DOMAIN\ldapUser" password="ldapPW"/>
</system.web>
```

here's a [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)